# How can I parse ffprobe output and run ffmpeg depending on the result?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have had incredible trouble building a binary of ffmpeg for Mac that works correctly for all of my needs. I have an older build that works great remuxing h264 video without problems but lacks a library I need, namely libspeex. I built a newer build based on ffmpeg's git that includes libspeex but crashes when trying to remux h264 from .flv files with bad timecodes (live dumps from rtmpdump). So I have two ffmpeg binaries that each do half of what I need. This is what I have as my current .command file:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv
do
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -async 1 "${f%.*}".mp4 && rmtrash "$f" || rmtrash "${f%.*}".mp4
done
```

This ffmpeg binary has libspeex included so it can decode speex audio in the .flv input files. What I'm looking to do is something like this pseudocode:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv
do
ffprobe input.flv
    if Stream #0:1 contains speex
        ffmpeg-speex -i input.flv -acodec copy -async 1 output.m4a
    fi
ffmpeg-h264 -i input.flv -vcodec copy output.mp4
MP4Box -add output.mp4 -add output.m4a finaloutput.mp4
done
```

Is something like this possible? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What does the output of ffprobe look like? It would probably be pretty simple to run grep on it.

Comment: `Input #0, flv, from '/Users/Greeny/Desktop/input.flv':Duration: 00:37:01.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 351 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: speex, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16`

Comment: Comments are impossible to format! -.-

Comment: How about I just ask where the newlines are supposed to be :P

Comment: input, duration, stream, stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run `grep` on its output and test whether it found your desired string:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv; do
    if ffprobe ${f} 2>&1 | egrep 'Stream #0:1.+speex'; then
        ffmpeg-speex -i ${f} -acodec copy -async 1 ${f/%.flv/.m4a}
        SPEEX_ADD="-add ${f/%.flv/.m4a}"
    fi
    ffmpeg-h264 -i ${f} -vcodec copy ${f/%.flv/.mp4}
    MP4Box -add ${f/%.flv/.mp4} ${SPEEX_ADD} ${f/%.flv/-final.mp4}
done
```

Assuming an input file `abc.flv`, `ffmpeg-speex` would output `abc.m4a`, `ffmpeg-h264` would output `abc.mp4`, and `MP4Box` would output `abc-final.mp4`.

**Edit:** Fixed to `grep` on stderr also; fixed problem where non-existent .m4a file might be given to `MP4Box` as an input.

Comment: It doesn't find speex in the line with this code :/ Just skips right to the video portion

Comment: Apparently ffprobe outputs to stderr. Added 2>&1 and it seems to work with extracting audio. Now I just need to find out why MP4Box is failing...

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem you're having, but I just fixed an issue with my answer wherein MP4Box would receive the .m4a file as an input, even if ffmpeg-speex never created it.

Answer (score 1):

The version of ffprobe that is out now has a -print_format flag that may be useful in your situation.  I had a similar issue where I wanted to get the length of a video.  I used the -print_format xml flag and then used xmllint on the result to get the value.  You will just need to look at the xml output from ffprobe and replace `string(.//format/@duration)` with the xpath to the elements you want.

```
XML=`ffprobe -v error -hide_banner -show_format -show_streams -print_format xml "$FILEPATH"`
DATA=`echo "$XML" | xmllint --xpath "string(.//format/@duration)" -`
```